# Root file system vs partition's file system

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel

1. Based on the first paragraph from [linfo](http://www.linfo.org/root_filesystem.html) as quoted below, one can conclude that root file system is actually the partition's file system where Linux is installed.

> The root filesystem is the filesystem that is contained on the same partition on which the root directory is located, and it is the filesystem on which all the other filesystems are mounted (i.e., logically attached to the system) as the system is booted up (i.e., started up).

2. If I understand file system in general correctly, it is a method of mapping/organizing the data like files in cabinets. In that sense, then directory hierarchy is the result of that.

Are the statements above true?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is not necessarily a direct relationship between a partition and a file system. A Linux or any OS installation can span multiple partitions. A file system is not inherently a root or a non root file system. Any file system can potentially be the root file system. Any unmounted file system can be mounted anywhere under the current root file system. Which file system is the root one usually change during the early stage of the boot process (from a ram based virtual one to the selected physical one).
2. Yes, a file system is indeed a way to organize data files in a hierarchy of directories.

Comment: I'm now totally confused with the concept of root file system.

Comment: Answer updated to clear that confusion or perhaps to add more of it ;-)